# Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 using Burg bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, burg

I am trying to make the Burg boot loader to work correctly. I install burg but it only sees Ubuntu and the recovery images. After I do `sudo update-burg`, I get this warning:

```
Generating burg.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic.efi.signed
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-27-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
  Windows Boot Manager is not yet supported by burg-mkconfig.
done
```

As you can see it recognizes my Windows 10 Home partition but won't appear in burg because it's not supported. I disabled Secure Boot and enabled CSM in the bios. I'm not sure what else I need to do to make it work. Can I edit the `burg-mkconfig` file to force it to appear?

Any help would be appreciated; thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last I heard, BURG was a BIOS-only boot loader. You appear to have an EFI-based installation of Windows. As such, BURG will be useless for booting Windows, or for controlling the overall boot process; the best you can do with BURG is to use it to select your Linux kernel, and leave the Windows-vs-Ubuntu boot choice to something else. I tried to track down more concrete information on this, but the best I found was package information at https://launchpad.net/~n-muench/+archive/ubuntu/burg/+packages, which indicates no EFI package for BURG. I couldn't even find an active home page for BURG, which could mean it's been abandoned (or maybe Google's just doing a very bad job on this search).

If you want to use BURG because of its graphical nature, you may want to look into my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) instead. Like BURG, rEFInd is graphics-oriented and themable, although the themes are not compatible. Unlike BURG, rEFInd is designed for EFI-based computers, which yours seems to be.

Note that if you're currently booting Ubuntu via BURG, installing rEFInd may be tricky, because you're booting Ubuntu in BIOS mode. You may need to create and boot via a USB flash drive or CD-R image of rEFInd (downloadable images are available on the [rEFInd downloads page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)). Once you boot in this way, you'll be in EFI mode, and can install the rEFInd PPA or Debian package. Alternatively, you can install rEFInd from Windows -- but the procedure for doing that is more tedious than the Ubuntu installation procedure, particularly if Secure Boot is active on your computer.

Comment: This burg shows last update Oct 2010:
https://code.google.com/p/burg/downloads/list  Better to convert Ubuntu to UEFI and use Rod's rEFInd. You can use Boot-Repair to convert from BIOS to UEFI in its advanced mode, but all it really is doing is uninstalling grub-pc and installing grub-efi-amd64.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response! rEFind works and looks great.